# How to enable IDE-emitted warnings for unused variables in C in VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I had a simple doubt while coding C in VSCode: how can I enable IDE-emitted warnings for unused variables and unused linked libraries?
I thought it was simple to solve, but I can't find any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be specific if you mean IDE-emitted warnings, or compiler-emitted ones. Also, what are "imports", do you mean header files? Linked libraries?

Comment: Isn't VSCode just an editor?  I thought you had to configure it to use a third party compiler (like clang or gcc).  If that is the case then you need to enable those warning by flags you pass to the compiler (like -Wall -pedantic).  Hopefully VSCode will automatically capture the compiler output and display it.